# Significato di "frangipolvere"

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Posso portarti con l’automobile del mister, insisté Rocco. Sapeva che la nuova Hudson Touring di Cozza suscitava l’ammirazione generale. Per i cerchioni d’argento, l’esile volante di radica, i sedili imbottiti, la copertura a soffietto, il vetro **frangipolvere**, il rombo strepitoso del motore e i fari immensi, come quelli delle navi, che troneggiavano ai lati del cofano.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "frangipolvere" in questo brano? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Una ricerca su Google, però, mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un vocabolo che si usa. Immagino sia un composto di ["frangere"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/frangere) e "polvere", ma ho visto che "frangere" significa  "rompere", "spezzare" e non capisco come il vetro di un'automobile possa rompere o spezzare la polvere.

Comment: Nel senso che fa da schermo o barriera contro la polvere, credo. Se stiamo parlando di quest'auto qui https://barrettjacksoncdn.azureedge.net/staging/carlist/items/Fullsize/Cars/116005/116005_Side_Profile_Web.jpg immagino si stia parlando del lunotto anteriore, che impedisce alla polvere di finire in faccia al guidatore.

Comment: A integrazione, la parola è costruita come “frangiflutti” (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/frangiflutti/).

Comment: Non so in che anni sia ambientato il romanzo; la Hudson Touring è degli anni '10 del ventesimo secolo e il nemico era, all'epoca, più la polvere che il vento, visto che la velocità era bassa e le strade erano sterrate.

Comment: @egreg: È ambientato in quest'epoca.

Comment: Visto che non l'ha ancora scritto nessuno, segnalo che il termine italiano corrente per il pannello di vetro anteriore di un'automobile è [parabrezza](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parabrezza).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nel testo, la parola viene utilizzata nel senso che fa da schermo o barriera contro la polvere.

@Charo ha confermato che il romanzo è ambientato nei primi anni del 20° secolo; quindi probabilmente stiamo parlando [di quest'auto qui](https://barrettjacksoncdn.azureedge.net/staging/carlist/items/Fullsize/Cars/116005/116005_Side_Profile_Web.jpg) (o un modello simile).

Immagino si stia parlando del parabrezza, che impedisce alla polvere di finire in faccia al guidatore; infatti @egreg ha giustamente fatto notare che all'epoca il "nemico" degli automobilisti era la polvere (per via della bassa velocità e delle strade sterrate) più che il vento.

Non saprei dire quando il termine "parabrezza" (ovvero vetro atto a difendere dal vento) abbia preso il sopravvento e sia diventato di uso comune.

Comment: Lo Zingarelli dà come datazione (credo per le prime occorrenze) di “parabrezza” il 1918. Per la precisione, “calco sul fr. _pare-brise_ ☼ 1918”. Google Ngrams sembra [mostrare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parabrezza&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparabrezza%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cparabrezza%3B%2Cc0) che abbia cominciato a diffondersi negli anni '30.